# Error de solicitud al servidor al clickear en una imagen ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

Muestro algunas imágenes en una página que al darle click me devuelve el error:

> "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500".

Para mostrar las imágenes utilizo un DataList con un ImageButton.
Revisando el codigo del error en el global.asax me encontré con que el error se debe a que `"Se excedió la longitud de solicitud máxima."`

Respecto a este tema encontré muchos posts (que no describen este problema ya que veo que lo tienen al subir las imágenes, yo lo tengo al intentar trabajar con las imágenes) indicando que se debe modificar el `maxRequestLength` en el web.config pero para poder guardar imágenes grandes ya que ASP.Net acepta por defecto archivos hasta 4MB.  Esto lo hice al momento de guardar las imágenes y funcionó perfecto, las imágenes las guardo y las muestro en la página sin problemas.

Dejo el web.config

```
    <location path="ClientesValidarImagenes.aspx">
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enable="false" maxRequestLength="1048576 "  requestLengthDiskThreshold="102400 " useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" executionTimeout="3600" targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Ahora cuando quiero seleccionar una imagen para agregarle una clase (y luego trabajar con los ID de las imágenes seleccionadas) me lanza el error que describí anteriormente y no llega a ejecutarse el `OnItemCommand` que es donde implemento el código para agregar la clase.

Código aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ClientesValidarImagenes.aspx.cs" Inherits="GD.ModuloParametros.ClientesValidarImagenes" EnableEventValidation="false"%>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <asp:Accordion ID="accValidarImagenes" runat="server" FadeTransitions="True" FramesPerSecond="40" Width="100%"
                    TransitionDuration="200" RequireOpenedPane="false" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
                     ContentCssClass="accordionContent" HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeader_selected">
            <Panes>
                <asp:AccordionPane ID="accPaneValidarImagenes" runat="server">
                    <Header>
                        <div class="accordionTitulo">
                            <span class="TituloFiltros" id="TituloFiltros">
                                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:GiroDinero, TituloValidarImagenesClientes%>"></asp:Literal>
                            </span> - Seleccione las imágenes que desea validar. 
                        </div>
                    </Header>
                    <Content>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:DataList ID="dlImagenes" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" HorizontalAlign="Center" PagedControlID="dlImagenes" CellSpacing="10" OnItemCommand="dlImagenes_ItemCommand" > 
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgValidarImagenes" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="150px" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("imagen") %>' OnClientClick="modImg(this)" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' CssClass="previewImg" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>                                                                                                    
                                </asp:DataList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dlImagenes"/>
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <div style="text-align:end; padding:10px;" id="divBtnValidar">
                             <asp:Button ID="btnValidar" runat="server" Text="Validar" CssClass="lnkDocumento" />
                        </div>
                    </Content>
                </asp:AccordionPane>
            </Panes>
        </asp:Accordion><br />
</asp:Content>
```

Dejo el aspx.cs pero no sé si es realmente necesario ya que a este punto no llega a ejecutarse el código.

```
protected void dlImagenes_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        dlImagenes.SelectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)dlImagenes.SelectedItem.FindControl("imgValidarImagenes");

        if (!img.CssClass.Contains("imagenSeleccionada"))
        {
            //agrego la clase
            img.CssClass = String.Join(" ", img.CssClass.Split(' ').Except(new string[] { " ", "imagenSeleccionada" }).Concat(new string[] { "imagenSeleccionada" }).ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            //Remuevo la clase
            img.CssClass = String.Join(" ", img.CssClass.Split(' ').Except(new string[] { " ", "imagenSeleccionada" }).ToArray()); 
        }
        
    }
```

Investigando un poco (bastante) vi que el tamaño de solicitud de la página no debe superar los 4MB - corríjanme si no es así - que es el `maxRequestLength` que configuré en el web.config (en muchos posts vi que se hace referencia que los 4MB corresponden al tamaño total de los archivos a subir pero viendo esto entiendo que es el peso total de la página). Busqué el tamaño de la solicitud y me devolvió 4.544.062 de Bytes (representados en un int) que serían 4.33MB por lo que se produce el error. Muestro en una imagen el tamaño del contenido de la página.
[image: captura]

Una aclaración más, las imágenes que guardo no llegan a pesar ni 1MB, pero cuando se hace la solicitud y ésta es menor a los 4.000.000 de bytes funciona todo sin prolemas.

La configuración del web.config por lo que veo es solo para que pueda subir imágenes mas grandes que los 4MB permitidos por default, pero ¿Como trabajo con las imágenes cargadas si la solicitud no puede superar los 4MB?

Comment: Estas corriendolo en tu servidor local?

Comment: Si, así es, no entiendo en qué estoy fallando, o si me falta algo

Comment: probablemente debas configurar el maxrequestlength del IIS

Comment: Lo pensé, fui a buscar la configuración a IIS/Encabezados de respuesta HTTP/Administrar sitio web/Configuración avanzada, y ahí tengo ``Límite de ancho de banda por segundo = 4294967295`` y ``Máximo de conexiones simultáneas = 4294967295``. No sé si es ahi donde debería configurarlo, y si es asi con esos tamaños debería funcionar, o no?